# Multiprocessing in python is not faster than sequential - I tried with Pool, Queue and Pipe. Why?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to process some MIDI files using the MIDO library. In this example, all I want to do is to take each file (150 files - just a single folder for now) from a database and make it a MIDI object. Firstly, I tried to do this with Threading library(it was slower), but then I found out that it doesn't make real parallelism, just concurrency. After that, I tried with Pool, Queue and Pipe from the multiprocessing library and all of them were slower than sequential( 12s vs 10s ). I tried to make the IO buffer from the MIDO library larger, but this also doesn't work. I have the following code:

POOL

```
def try_p(name):
    return mido.MidiFile(DATABASE_PATH + name)


start = time.time()

p = Pool(processes=4)
for i in p.imap_unordered(try_p,  listdir(DATABASE_PATH), 4):
    print i

p.close()

print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start)
```

PIPE

```
def read_midi(ip, op):
    files = op.recv()
    res = [mido.MidiFile(DATABASE_PATH + f) for f in files]
    op.send(res)
    op.close()

number_of_threads = 4
songs = []
processes = []
pipes = []
ldir = listdir(DATABASE_PATH)
files = list(chunks(ldir, len(ldir)/number_of_threads))

for i in range(number_of_threads):
    pipe = Pipe()
    pipes.append(pipe)
    pipe[0].send(files[i])

    process = Process(target=read_midi, name="Fml" + str(i), args=pipe)
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)

midis = []

for pipe in pipes:
    midis.append(pipe[0].recv())

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print(len(midis))
```

QUEUE

```
def read_midi(files, queue):
    res = [mido.MidiFile(DATABASE_PATH + f) for f in files]
    queue.put(res)

number_of_threads = 4
songs = []
processes = []
input_queue = Queue()
output_queue = Queue()
ldir = listdir(DATABASE_PATH)
files = list(chunks(ldir, len(ldir)/number_of_threads))

for i in range(number_of_threads):
    process = Process(target=read_midi, name="Fml" + str(i), args=(files[i],     output_queue))
    process.start()
    processes.append(process)

midis = []
for i in range(number_of_threads):
    midis.append(output_queue.get())

for process in processes:
    process.join()

print(len(midis))
```

What can I do to get a better performance?

EDIT: I read all the files from the folder in a loop and the reading lasts for ~0.006 s - I do not think it is IO bound

Answer (score 1):

From what I see, you are not doing anything with those files, just reading them. In that case, your process is probably I/O bound, meaning that the access to the disk/database is the limiting factor. In this case, using multiple processes will only add some communication overhead.

Unfortunately, using multiple processes can help only if your bottleneck is actually *processing*.

If you are using a database, it may help to pack together multiple queries, instead of making a single query for each file.

Comment: I am not only reading them,  MIDO library is processing the files here:mido.MidiFile(DATABASE_PATH + name)

Comment: I apologize, I got it wrong. If you are sure that is the limiting step, I'm not sure what's wrong here :(

Comment: I tested your code, and in my machine I get a ~2x speedup using four processes though. Overheads still appear to be quite significant.

Comment: did you test it with mido library and how many files did you have?

Comment: I used mido library, and I repeated the process 800 times on the same file. I go from ~17 sec in serial to ~8 sec using imap.

Comment: interesting.i can't figure out what's the problem then.thank you

Comment: This is what I think it is happening: when you use multiprocessing, the generation of the objects is actually being parallelized. However, the generated objects are quite large, and it takes time to pickle/unpickle them when you move them around. Especially in the main process, which needs to unpickle all of them. Since what mido.MidiFile pretty much reads the file and generate an object, doesn't do any crazy hardcore computation on it, it is understandable that pickling/communication/unpickling could compete.

Answer (score 0):

Your pool code seems allright, have you try map?:

```
def try_p(name):
    return mido.MidiFile(DATABASE_PATH + name)


start = time.time()

p = Pool(processes=4)
res = p.map(try_p,  listdir(DATABASE_PATH), 4):
p.close()
print 'Time elapsed: %s' % (time.time() - start) 
for e in res:
    print e
```

If your code does not speed up probably **the cost of building the extra processed are more expensive than the computation itself**.

Comment: @Bristina, `imap` just let you start iterating once the first value is available, since it is yielding them, `map` waits till all are finish, i guess is what i explained in there